# Goroutines channels and "stopping short"

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm reading/working through [Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines), but i'm having trouble understanding the **Stopping short** section. We have the following functions:

```
func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int, 1) // enough space for the unread inputs

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    in := gen(2, 3)

    // Distribute the sq work across two goroutines that both read from in.
    c1 := sq(in)
    c2 := sq(in)

    // Consume the first value from output.
    out := merge(c1, c2)
    fmt.Println(<-out) // 4 or 9
    return
    // Apparently if we had not set the merge out buffer size to 1
    // then we would have a hanging go routine. 
}
```

Now, if you notice line `2` in `merge`, it says we make the out `chan` with `buffer` size 1, because this is enough space for the unread inputs. However, I'm almost positive that we should allocate a `chan` with `buffer` size 2. In accordance with this code sample:

```
c := make(chan int, 2) // buffer size 2
c <- 1  // succeeds immediately
c <- 2  // succeeds immediately
c <- 3  // blocks until another goroutine does <-c and receives 1
```

Because this section implies that a `chan` of `buffer` size 3 would not block. Can anyone please clarify/assist my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program sends two values to the channel `out` and reads one value from the channel `out`.  One of the values is not received.

If the channel is unbuffered (capacity 0), then one of the sending goroutines will block until the program exits.  This is a leak.

If the channel is created with a capacity of 1, then both goroutines can send to the channel and exit. The first value sent to the channel is received by `main`. The second value remains in the channel.

If the main function does not receive a value from the channel `out`, then a channel of capacity 2 is required to prevent the goroutines from blocking indefinitely.